# Armadillo C++ Matrix library - printing a matrix of chars

Tags: c++, armadillo

I made a character matrix as follows

```
Mat <char>pathMap(rowCount, rowCount);
    pathMap.fill('?');
    pathMap.raw_print;
```

I also tried regular print. However, both cases print out something like this

63 63 63
63 63 63
63 63 63

63 is the ASCII value for the character. Is there any feature in armadillo that will just let me print out the character directly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the matrix, I was able to save the matrix to the cout stream

ie pathMap.save(cout)

However, the best method for me ended up being to simply print out each element individually.